# Run same UPDATE query until there is affected row in last run (MySQL 5.5)

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, mariadb

I want to `UPDATE` all `WHERE parameter_id IS NULL` `parameter_id` to `MAX(parameter_id)+1`, but I do not want to set all `WHERE parameter_id IS NULL` to same `MAX(parameter_id)+1`. I want every single `parameter_id` to have own be `MAX(parameter_id)+1` - after updating single row, current `MAX(parameter_id)+1` will change.

This query does the job, but I need to run it 50.000 times. So, is it possible to run this query while `WHERE parameter_id IS NULL`?

```
UPDATE myTable
SET parameter_id=
  (SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT MAX(parameter_id)+1
      FROM myTable) AS t)
WHERE parameter_id IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

This `parameter_id` is not `PRIMARY KEY` nor it is `UNIQUE`. `parameter_id` can/will be changed, multiple rows can/will have same `parameter_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a loop to iterate through all the records .This should do the trick.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_Records ()
BEGIN

DECLARE nrRecords INT;
DECLARE maxId INT;
DECLARE iterator INT;

SELECT MAX(parameter_id) into maxId FROM myTable;
SELECT COUNT(*) into nrRecords FROM myTable where parameter_id is null;
for iterator in 1..nrRecords loop
   UPDATE myTable SET parameter_id = maxId+iterator WHERE parameter_id IS NULL LIMIT 1;
end loop;
END;
```

Second option is to declare in the procedure above a cursor and iterate through it . The result would be the same.

Comment: It gets lot of errors, for example: `Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'DECLARE nrRecords NUMBER' at line 1`

Comment: Given it's MySQL you are using , declare the variables as listed above

Comment: Same error `Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'DECLARE nrRecords NUMBER' at line 3`. Do I understand correctly > MySQL has `WHILE`, `ITERATE` etc. but I can use it only in procedures?

Comment: Indeed there are . The block above should also be included in a procedure ( add CREATE PROCEDURE update_Records () above the block )